# I want to add rewriteurls in my existing .htacess file.. But when i add new its not working

Tags: .htaccess

below is my .htacess file code which is working fine

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

but when i add below new rewriterules then that new rules not working. its opening php wampserver main page..

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+).html?$ detail-page.php?network=$1&country=$2&category=$3&subcategory=$4&package_id=$5    [QSA,L]
```

kindly tell me where and how to add this new rule so it should work

Comment: How have you defined the server config / virtual host? What's the document root? Where exactly are you adding this rule?

Comment: i am adding it into my subdomain. actually this is hostgator server and i enabled .htacess from them for my subdomain.. they added .htacess ifmodule code into .htaccess file. but when i am adding my rules then its not working

Comment: Different to the `.htaccess` file you posted above? - where is that?

Comment: .htacess file is on root folder...